# How can I edit usr/bin

Tags: command-line, 13.10

I'm trying to run Chromium OS from within Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit. I'm running into a couple of issues, and one of the possible solutions I've found requires editing a file called usr/bin/chromeos. I assumed I could enter that file name in the terminal and it would give me the text editor so I could edit it. However, I get this response:

```
$ /usr/bin/chromeos
bash: /usr/bin/chromeos: No such file or directory
```

What can I do? I think I've had this happen before when trying to edit other files like this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit the question to link to the solution you mention? What you're suggesting doesn't make much technical sense so we might be able to interpret it better for you.

Comment: You may want to check whether it exists first... Run `ls /usr/bin | grep ^c` and see if `chromeos` is in the list.

Comment: Did you build chromeos? Did you download it? If you built it, you would need to cd into the build directory. We would need more information and a link possibly to the instructions you are following would be great as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see the content of a file use

```
sudo cat /usr/bin/chromeos
```

If you want to edit the file

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/chromeos
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to edit a file called `/usr/bin/chromeos`, you would need to use an editor. It's also in an area of the disk that is habitually owned by root, so you'd need to elevate your permissions to do it.

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/chromeos      # text mode editor
sudo -i gedit /usr/bin/chromeos  # graphical editor
```

But how much that actually helps is not certain at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Your needed file is most likely `/usr/sbin/chromeos` not `/usr/bin/chromeos` (note the `s`). And you have to open it just like Oli said in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this file by executing the following command:

```
find /* | grep chromeos
```

and if you need to narrow down the results, this command might help:

```
find /* | grep "bin/chromeos"
```

Additionally, if the file *is* located at `/usr/bin/chromeos` then you would need to use the `sudo` command to edit the file and you would also need to specify the text editor you would like to use such as `nano` or `gedit` like in this example:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/chromeos
```

However, we already know that this file does not exist at `/usr/bin/chromeos` so you will need to use the actual path to the file you found using the `find` command earlier.